# php70-php-opcache preventing CMS install

Tags: apache-2.4, php7, opcache

We have an **Apache 2.4** box with **php7** from the Remi repo working fine. PHP processing is as expected. This is apart from the **php7-php-opcache** package which, upon install, prevents the successful installation of **Wordpress**. The original `wp-config.php` is used instead of an updated one.

Now, I know that this is just doing what a cache should be doing - storing things and returning them on request. However, this design is going to be a problem in our environment as CMS installs happen all the time. Every failed install will result in a support ticket.

I am keen to use **opcache** due to the performance benefits. I used to use xcache and APC and never saw them interfere in this way. I could set a short expiry time but it'll still mess up the CMS installs. Any other ideas? Is **opcache** broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hit by opcache.revalidate_freq=2 option

This is probably a wordpress issue, which sould call the opcache_invalidate function after writing this file.

But after "opcache.revalidate_freq", the new file should be used, so I think this is only a temporary issue.

Comment: See: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37339

Comment: I agree it is most likely temporary. A few weeks ago I set up a test box and didn't have this problem as I recall. Thanks for the bug report link. Will consider this answered by that.